# How to insert only the type time sqlite

Tags: sqlite

How can I insert a type `time` in the database (sqlite)?

Is there any type for that? I'm looking for this because I need filter by time, I don´t need the datetime, just the time. (time format should be 24h)

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Use an `int`

Comment: if I use ``Integer`` how can I order properly for example 17:00 and 00:00 @juergend

Comment: `1700` is greater than `0`. So all good. By definition `00:00` is the start of the day and  `23:59` the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite` has no TIME datatype, according to [sqlite.org/datatype3.html](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) so you can assign `TEXT` as datatype.

Comment: It´s what I'm thinking but how can I sort by time with that?¿ any suggestion? @Nazmul

Comment: Convert it to datatime when you want to filter. Actually it does not any mean to save time without date. I do not know your situation.